# sifr 3 not working in IE 8 64bit (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, 64-bit, internet-explorer, sifr3

love sifr - use it all the time...

but i've noticed that it does not replace text in IE 8 64bit version...
works fine in regular IE 8 on windows 7, but not the 64bit version...
for a test, anyone viewing this on a 64bit windows machine please take a look at the demo itself in IE 64bit:

http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/svn/test/distribution/demo

no replacements?

dunno about other versions of IE nor do i know about 64bit vista... this should be looked into as windows7 gains popularity and replaces the rest of the windows OS'...

hoping someone has an answer as this great script is essential to our designs...

thanks!
sank

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported on IE x64.

Answer (score 0):

just found this out myself:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html

;)